# Linq to XML query is too slow

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

An linq-xml query is taking more time to execute. Please guide me to simply the query or any options like compiled query(which is not available for xml).

Query goes like this:

```
rootNode.Descendants(ns + "childNodeName")
                       .Where(
                           childNode =>
                           childNode.Descendants(ns + "grandChild")
                                  .Any(grandChild=> grandChild.Attribute("attribute").Value.Equals("condString")));
```

Comment: Please give us more context - how big is this document, how many child nodes are there, etc? Could the `grandChild` elements really be anywhere under `childNodeName`, or do you know more about the structure? How long is it taking?

Answer (score 0):

`Elements()` is faster than `Descendants()` so if you just need the children and not all descendants, then use `Elements()`. Based on the names you use, this sounds like being the case.

Otherwise, show us your XML.